# How we can perform Edit Option in Metadata properties of uploaded file In DAM?

Tags: adobe, aem

I need to edit the properties(Metadata properties) of uploaded file stored in DAM. How it can be performed programatically? Is is possible to edit the metadata properties without uploading the file again?

For editing the values stored in metadata (dam) , here I'm uploading the same file using `<input type="file" id="file_link" name="file" class="file_link_class">` but is there any other way to edit the values stored in metadata properties(dam) ?? Or is it possible to get the Asset Path from DAM in jsp and pass it to servlet as file to get the values as file format using `RequestParameter file = request.getRequestParameter("file");` ? 
Because when im trying to create file using `asset = assetManager.createAsset(editfilepath,file1, mimeType, true);` file 1 -> not accepting to create.

Comment: I guess the simple way is after uploading asset on node creation event trigger a servlet that can modify metadata properties.

Comment: Currently I'm updating by uploading the same file with edited values for the fields and save it again. So its like uploading the file again which will replace the older file. My doubt is 'Is there any possible way to edit the values in dam without uploading the file' ? through code ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom Worflow Step Class, implementing 'com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess', which is going to read/update the asset metadata in the execute() method. After that you have two options.

1. Or you put this workflow step in the existing workflow model 'Dam Update Asset' (http://localhost:4502/cf#/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html)
2. Or, create a dedicated workflow models which is going to call this step. And create too a custom workflow launcher, triggered when you asset will be uploaded, and then call you dedicated workflow model.

Comment: How to access the metadata node in execute() method?